# Random movement - Windows Pipe Screensaver

Tags: objective-c, c, algorithm

Many of you may know [the classic windows screen saver](http://chrome-hacks.net/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/aboutinternets.jpg). Does anyone have any idea how this was programmed in 3D or 2D?  No real code necessary - just the an overall explanation of the algorithm would be great.

Comment: There's a clone in [xscreensaver](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/) you can inspect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](http://src.chromium.org/svn/branches/official/build_149/src/chrome/browser/about_internets_status_view.cc) is screenshot from Chrome. In chrome it is programmed very easily:

```
file_util::AppendToPath(&path, L"sspipes.scr");
  CreateProcess(NULL, ...
```

or: Open a windows Pipe screensaver file, and Run it.

Source of xscreensaver's version is: xscreensaver-4.16/hacks/glx/pipes.c in the xscreensaver-4.16.tar.bz2 (or other version of the same package). [Online version of the file](http://fossies.org/dox/xscreensaver-5.20/pipes_8c_source.html).

UPDATE: How it works: It uses OpenGL to make the things beautiful

Each tube addittion is drawn as cylinder and a sphere:

```
    glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
    for (an = 0.0; an <= 2.0 * M_PI; an += M_PI / 12.0) {
            glNormal3f((COSan_3 = cos(an) / 3.0), (SINan_3 = sin(an) / 3.0), 0.0);
            glVertex3f(COSan_3, SINan_3, one_third);
            glVertex3f(COSan_3, SINan_3, -one_third);
    }
    glEnd();
```

Rotation in space is done by `glRotatef` before `glBegin`. All rotations are 90 degrees only.

End sphere is glu object:

```
    quadObj = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(quadObj, (GLenum) GLU_FILL);
    gluSphere(quadObj, radius, 16, 16);
    gluDeleteQuadric(quadObj);
```

For bends, a lot of code is used to draw (function myElbow).

For not to intersect, the 3d array is used with flags "this point of space contains a pipe". All pipes have integer coordinates and are parallel to the axis. Perspective correction is from 3d library (opengl/direct3d).

Main function with logic is `draw_pipes`.

It draws a sphere, selects a direction as random and pipe run begins. At every step there is a random shance (with 20% prob) of bending. Also, neiborhods are checked at every step to prevent collisions. Is there is no free space to continue a pipe or the pipe is long enough (may be random too), it will stop and new pipe begins from random point.

Answer (score 1):

It was done using OpenGL (back when MS was excited about OpenGL on Windows). While I can't speak authoritatively about the rest (not sure I've ever seen the source code) it *looks* like a pretty straightforward matter of choosing a direction (up, down, left, right, forward, backward) and a distance, with some bounds to keep it all in a cube.

The pipe has some particular diameter, and you can select a bitmap to be textured onto the pipe if you want. If you don't use a texture, it can/will choose colors. It's old enough, I believe it's written to use only the 20 (16?) colors defined by Windows as the basic palette normally supported on almost any graphics adapter -- but it's been quite a while since mainstream hardware was nearly that restricted.